# Why is my multiplying not working?

Tags: java

I have to create a class and a tester program called fraction. A fractions is created and it can be simplified, multiplied, divided, added, and subtracted. When ever I use the multiply method it keeps returning the square of the second multiply and I am not sure why.

```
  class Fraction{

     private static int numerator;
     private static int denominator;

  public Fraction(int num, int den){
  numerator = num;
  denominator = den;
  }


  public static int getNumerator(){
      return numerator;
  }

  public static int getDenominator(){
     return denominator;
   }

  public static String getFraction(){
     return (numerator + "/" + denominator);
  }

  public static void setNumerator(int x){
    numerator = x;
  }

  public static void setDenominator(int x){
     denominator = x;
  }

  public static Fraction multiply(Fraction fraction, Fraction fractionTwo){
     Fraction newFraction = new Fraction(fraction.getNumerator() * fractionTwo.getNumerator(), fraction.getDenominator() * fractionTwo.getDenominator());
     return reduce(newFraction.getNumerator(), newFraction.getDenominator());
  }

  public static Fraction divide(Fraction fraction, Fraction fractionTwo){
     Fraction newFraction = new Fraction(fraction.getNumerator() * fractionTwo.getDenominator(), fraction.getDenominator() *fractionTwo.getNumerator());
     return reduce(newFraction.getNumerator(), newFraction.getDenominator());

  }

   public static Fraction commonDenominator(Fraction fraction, Fraction fractionTwo){
      int x = 2;
      Fraction multiply = new Fraction(x, x);
      for(x = multiply.getNumerator(); fraction.getDenominator() != fractionTwo.getDenominator(); x++){
          multiply.setNumerator(x);
          multiply.setDenominator(x);

       }
      multiply(multiply, fraction);
      multiply(multiply, fractionTwo);
      Fraction commonDenominator = new Fraction(x, x);
      return commonDenominator;
    }

    public static Fraction addition(Fraction fraction, Fraction fractionTwo){
       Fraction commonDenominator = commonDenominator(fraction, fractionTwo);
       Fraction fractionAdd = multiply(fraction, commonDenominator);
       Fraction fractionAddTwo = multiply(fractionTwo, commonDenominator);
       Fraction newFraction = new Fraction((fractionAddTwo.getNumerator() + fractionAdd.getNumerator()), (fractionAddTwo.getDenominator() + fractionAdd.getDenominator()));
       return newFraction;
    }

    public static Fraction subtraction(Fraction fraction, Fraction fractionTwo){
       Fraction commonDenominator = commonDenominator(fraction, fractionTwo);
       Fraction fractionAdd = multiply(fraction, commonDenominator);
       Fraction fractionAddTwo = multiply(fractionTwo, commonDenominator);
       Fraction newFraction = new Fraction((fractionAdd.getNumerator() - fractionAddTwo.getNumerator()), (fractionAdd.getDenominator() + fractionAddTwo.getDenominator()));
       return newFraction;
    }

    public static boolean equals(Fraction fraction){
       if(numerator == fraction.getNumerator() && denominator == fraction.getDenominator()){
          return true;
       }
       else{
          return false;
       }
    }

    public static double decimalValue(Fraction fraction){
       double decimal = (double)fraction.getNumerator()/fraction.getDenominator();
       return decimal;
    }  
    public static Fraction reduce(int numerator, int denominator){

       if(numerator==0&&denominator==0){
          numerator = 0;
          denominator = 0;
       }
       else{
          for(int x = Math.max(numerator, denominator); x>0; x--){
             if(denominator == numerator){
                numerator = 1;
                denominator = 1;
             }
             else if(numerator == 0){
                numerator = 0;
                denominator = 1;
             }
             else if(numerator%x==0 && denominator%x==0){
                numerator = numerator/x;
                denominator = denominator/x;    
             }
          }
       }
       Fraction fraction = new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
       return fraction;
    }


    public String toString(){
       reduce(numerator, denominator);
       return (numerator) + "/" + (denominator);
    }

 }
```

Comment: `static vs instance` methods.

Comment: what error is reported?

Comment: On which line does the error actually occur?

Comment: My comment was wrong, carry on.

Comment: @azurefrog I dont know why I had it in my head that this was C.

Comment: Your fraction method is not used once in your reduce method.. Why is it a parameter? Your equals method is not overridden correctly...

Comment: I think you should review the basics before coding an advanced code

Answer (score 1):

This method should be static, and then you call it `Fraction.multiply(f1, f2)`

```
public static Fraction multiply(Fraction fraction, Fraction fractionTwo) {
    Fraction newFraction = new Fraction(fraction.getNumerator() * fractionTwo.getNumerator(), fraction.getDenominator() * fractionTwo.getDenominator());
    return newFraction.reduce();
}
```

or method should use the current status of the object. Then you call it `new Fraction(3,4).multiply(f1)`. This method can look like this:

```
public Fraction multiply(Fraction fractionTwo) {
    Fraction newFraction = new Fraction(numerator * fractionTwo.getNumerator(), denominator * fractionTwo.getDenominator());
    return newFraction.reduce();
}
```

So, all the code can look like this.

```
class Fraction {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction(int num, int den) {
        numerator = num;
        denominator = den;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Fraction r1 = new Fraction (2,3); // 2/3
        Fraction r2 = new Fraction(3,4); // 3/4
        Fraction r3 = r1.multiply(r2); // 2/3 * 3/4
        System.out.println(r3); // print 1/2
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public Fraction multiply(Fraction fractionTwo) {
        Fraction newFraction = new Fraction(numerator * fractionTwo.getNumerator(), denominator * fractionTwo.getDenominator());
        return newFraction.reduce();
    }

    public Fraction reduce() {
        for (int x = Math.max(numerator, denominator); x > 0; x--) {
            if (numerator % x == 0 && denominator % x == 0) {
                numerator = numerator / x;
                denominator = denominator / x;
            }
            if (denominator == numerator) {
                numerator = 1;
                denominator = 1;
            }

        }
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return numerator + " / " + denominator;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to the second method, but for some reason it is squaring the fraction in the parameter. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You asked about "Why you get the compile error". I answered for that question. I don't know what should happen when you call the method on this object. I try understand, but the `reduce` method a little confused me. Maybe you should write other question and explain what you expected and what you get.

Comment: Ok well thank you for explaining the compile error. I think it may be something wrong with the multiply method because it is reducing correctly.

Comment: You welcome, I think that was your question. Or was not?

Comment: I think you should learn some more about object oriented programming. Because your code didn't look good, especially methods `toString(f1)`, `equals(f1, f2)` and `reduce(f1)`.

Comment: I haven't worked that much with object oriented programming so I am just trying to figure out what I did wrong and I some of my other errors so I am going to fix those too.

Comment: I think you have a error in `reduce` method. Your loop condition should look like this `for (int x = Math.max(numerator, denominator); x > 0; x--)`.

Comment: I had changed it to that earlier. I know it works when I it is 3/6 it prints out 1/2 but it isn't right when I multiply

Comment: Ok. I see the problem. Method `multiply` should return `return newFraction.reduce(newFraction);` instead of `return reduce(newFraction);`

Comment: I changed my code so now the parameter for reduce are the numerator and denominator so they are ints.

Comment: I edited my answer. I added my code that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give the same answer as you already got. So I answer regarding the `toString()` method.

Please keep in mind that any object inherits from the class `object`. And if you use the method `toString()` you override it from the object class.

Here you can see the methods inside the object class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

As you can see, the `toString()` method represents the object where it is used and it requires **no parameter**. So if you implement it as follows:

```
public String toString() {
    return **your Code**;
}
```

Then this one should give no weird numbers and letters (which are actually the current memory address of the object).

All the best

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it was squaring the last number instead of multiplying the two numbers. It was because my instance variables were static an they weren't supposed to be.